# Reenabling Raspberry Pi passwordless sudo

Tags: sudo, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I am running Bullseye with non "pi" account and wanted to require my user to always type in a sudo password. I used sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd and changed

```
myaccount ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

to

```
myaccount ALL=(ALL) PASSWD: ALL
```

That worked fine. Now I've decided that I'm sick of typing in my password so I want to change it back to no password. But I changed the line, using visudo, back to
myaccount ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
and it's still requiring a password. I've logged out/back in and rebooted. No change. I never saw any visudo errors (in fact, I wondered what a visudo error looked like so I intentionally mistyped something in the file and I got the normal syntax error, then typed x to exit without saving. So I know visudo is doing its syntax checker).
Any assistance is appreciated.
Scott.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain *why* you've edited an *alternative* `sudoers` file??

All you need is: `sudo visudo`. That ***may*** explain your problem. If you feel you've *done the right thing* by editing this *alternative* file, read on:

At the bottom of your `sudoers` file, you may find a line similar to the following:

`@includedir /etc/sudoers.d`

That refers to a folder that may contain the following files:

```bash
$ ls -l /etc/sudoers.d
total 16
-r--r----- 1 root root  36 Apr 29  2019 010_at-export
-r--r----- 1 root root  27 Oct 18  2016 010_pi-nopasswd
-r--r----- 1 root root 211 Oct 19  2021 010_proxy
-r--r----- 1 root root 958 Feb 27  2021 README
```

If there are any files in this directory, you should look closely at them. They are all executed by `run-parts` (ref `man run-parts`), and they may contain the answer you're seeking. Perhaps:

> myaccount ALL=(ALL) PASSWD: ALL

If that *doesn't* fix your issue, we need more details on exactly how you've arrived at where you are.